# Find all differentiable functions $f$ such that $f(f(x))=f'(x)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, functional-equations

Here is a problem I made up:

Find all differentiable functions $f$ from the reals to the reals such that $f(f(x))=f'(x)$ for all real $x$.

Comment: It can't be $f(x)=A_{1}x^{a_1}+A_{2}x^{a_2}+\cdots +A_nx^{a_n}$ for any real $A_i,a_i$ (wlog $\max\{a_i\}=a_1$), since $a_1^2=a_1-1$ is impossible.

Comment: if we assume that $f(0)=0$ then $f=0$ see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1092217/solution-of-f-circ-f-f)

Comment: see also [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408004/does-a-non-trivial-solution-exist-for-fx-ffx)